# How can I return failure message from stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have a stored procedure that I am using to if an entry exists in the database. The problem I am having is that it always returns "commands executed successfully even if I pass in the wrong parameters and this is affecting my testing via the API.

This is my SP here below

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO



    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Validate_Entry]
    @Password varchar(250),
    @Email varchar(250)
    --@Result varchar(250) output 
    --@firstName varchar(250), 
    --@lastName varchar(250)
    AS
    DECLARE @ResultValue int
    BEGIN
    IF  not exists (Select  firstName, lastName, emailaddress,[password] from User_Table  where emailaddress=@email and Password = @Password and Active = 1)
      BEGIN
        SET  @ResultValue = -5 
        RETURN @ResultValue
      END   
    ELSE
      BEGIN 
      SET  @ResultValue = 0
        RETURN @ResultValue
       END
    END
```

Comment: RETURN @ResultValue is typically used for checking the code execution (if 0 code executed successfully, if <>0 then something went wrong). In case you want to stick with your approach, you need to capture the returned value:  `declare @ret int; exec @ret=[dbo].[sp_Validate_Entry]; select iif(@ret=-5, 'wrong uname/pass', 'success');`

Comment: @Zidane; Please mark the answer as an accepted if it was helpful or comment it if-else.

Answer (score 0):

Raises a customer exception and transfers execution to a CATCH block :

```
IF  not exists (Select  firstName, lastName, emailaddress,[password] from User_Table  where emailaddress=@email and Password = @Password and Active = 1)
      BEGIN
        SET  @ResultValue = -5 
        THROW 51000, 'The record does not exist.', 1;  
        RETURN @ResultValue
      END
```